# How do you get total contributions with Githubs API v4

Tags: api, github, github-api, graphql, apollo

I have been looking through the Github V4 API docs and I cannot seem to find a way to query total contributions for the year (as displayed on your github profile). Has anyone managed to use the new API to grab some statistics from your personal profile?

I am using graphQL and a Personal Access Token on github, and managed to get minimal user profile data; username, profile name etc.

Comment: Found a schema-request for this on the Github Platform Forum:

https://platform.github.community/t/cant-access-the-contributors-of-a-repository/1848

Answer (score 8):

The [ContributionsCollection](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/contributionscollection/) object provides total contributions for each contribution type between two dates.

Note: `from` and `to` can be a maximum of one year apart, for a longer timeframe make multiple requests.

```
query ContributionsView($username: String!, $from: DateTime!, $to: DateTime!) {
  user(login: $username) {
    contributionsCollection(from: $from, to: $to) {
      totalCommitContributions
      totalIssueContributions
      totalPullRequestContributions
      totalPullRequestReviewContributions
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no API for this as such. So there are two ways to go about it. Simple data scraping the user url or looping through each repo user has forked and then count the contribution. The later one will be more time consuming. The first one is much more reliable as it is cached by github. Below is a python approach to fetch the same

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

GITHUB_URL = 'https://github.com/'


def get_contributions(usernames):
    """
    Get a github user's public contributions.
    :param usernames: A string or sequence of github usernames.
    """
    contributions = {'users': [], 'total': 0}

    if isinstance(usernames, str) or isinstance(usernames, unicode):
        usernames = [usernames]

    for username in usernames:
        response = requests.get('{0}{1}'.format(GITHUB_URL, username))

        if not response.ok:
            contributions['users'].append({username: dict(total=0)})
            continue

        bs = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        total = bs.find('div', {'class': 'js-yearly-contributions'}).findNext('h2')
        contributions['users'].append({username: dict(total=int(total.text.split()[0].replace(',', '')))})
        contributions['total'] += int(total.text.split()[0].replace(',', ''))

    return json.dumps(contributions, indent=4)
```

PS: Taken from https://github.com/garnertb/github-contributions

For later approach there is a npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-user-contributions

But I would recommend using the scraping approach only