# Is there a way to fetch the number of contribution of GitHub profile in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, github

Is there a way to fetch the number of contributions in the last year using Javascript (client-side)? Note that number is for the public and private repository

[image]

Comment: I suggest using `got` and the GitHub API located at https://docs.github.com/en/rest.

Comment: I'm creating a page on blogger and I don't think that service gives you the ability to use anything like that. @awesomemaker3000

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18262288/9157799

Comment: @MImamPratama Tried that first and it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried many solutions and I improved one to get the following which works the best for me:

1. Create a function in Javascript

```js
function get_contribution() {
    profile_url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://github.com/users/USERNAME/contributions";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'document';

    xhr.open('GET', profile_url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var response = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByClassName('f4 text-normal mb-2')[0].innerText;
            // get only the numbers in response
            contribution = response.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            
            // The number of contributions is now saved in the contribution variable
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

- Change USERNAME to the GitHub username you want
- Note that you have to use "cors" or it won't work

2. Now you can use that function anywhere but in my case, I will call it on page load and set it somewhere in the HTML:

```js
onload = function(){
    get_contribution();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the unofficial `Github Contributions API` located at [this site](https://github-contributions-api.deno.dev)

Here is an example

```js
async function getContributions(username) {
  var data = await (await fetch(`https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://github-contributions-api.deno.dev/${username}.json`)).json();
  console.log(data.totalContributions)
}
getContributions("octocat") // Returns 0, as Octocat has zero contributions
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a GraphQL query ([GitHub API v4](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql)) and a [ContributionsCollection](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#contributionscollection) object.

Define `from` by `now` minus one year, and `to` by `now`.

```js
   var to = new Date();
   var year  = to.getFullYear();
   var month = to.getMonth();
   var day   = to.getDate();
   var from = new Date(year - 1, month, day);
```

Use [graphql.js](https://github.com/octokit/graphql.js/) to then call, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131513/6309):

```
query ContributionsView($username: String!, $from: DateTime!, $to: DateTime!) {
  user(login: $username) {
    contributionsCollection(from: $from, to: $to) {
      totalCommitContributions
      totalIssueContributions
      totalPullRequestContributions
      totalPullRequestReviewContributions
    }
  }
}
```

Once the script works outside your Blogger page, [you can include it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134524/6309) with a `<script src=...>` element.

Comment: it requires me to add my credentials, which isn't the best when it comes to putting something like that on the client side, am I right?

Comment: Indeed, unless you can fetch the token at runtime from an external vault.